# "Division by zero" error in a nested for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, division, zero

The purpose of this script:

Write a script that counts from 1 to 10 in steps of 1. For each number, display whether that
number is an odd or even number, and also display a message if the number is a prime number.
Display this information within an HTML table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Exercise 1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css" />
<style type="text/css">
  th { text-align: left; background-color: #999; }
  th, td { padding: 0.4em; }
  tr.alt td { background: #ddd; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Exercise 1</h2>

<table cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 20em; border: 1px solid #666;">
  <tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Parity</th>
    <th>Primality</th>
  </tr>
    <?php 
    $n=10;
    for ($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++){
    echo ($i%2 != 0)? '<tr class = "alt">':'<tr>'; ?>
    <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo ($i%2 != 0)? "Odd":"Even";?></td>
    <td><?php 

    $k=0;
    for ($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++){
        if ($i%$j=0) $k++; //Where the error occurs
    }
    echo ($k=2 || $k=1)?"Prime":"Composite";?>
    </td></tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please strip all the HTML from your question, so we can focus on the core problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$i%$j=0`

Assigns `$j` as `0` and then tries to do `$i % 0`;

You want

`($i % $j) == 0`

There's another mistake in the same way with the `echo`.

Consider also formatting your code with spaces to make it more readable.

Comment: Thanks, it's that equal sign. And after rectifying the other two equal signs, the script works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

`if ($i%$j=0)` should probably be `if ($i%$j==0)`